String Expansion program gives incorrect output
Input - 'a2b3c1'
Expected Output - 'aabbbc'
Actual Output -  'aaabbbbcc'
I am not sure why is it printing the input alpha char again. What could I possibly change here to get the right output
The following is my program:
public class stringExpansionAndCompression {

    public void getStringInput() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the String value: ");
        String inputStr = reader.readLine();
        String output = stringExpansionRegEx(inputStr);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public String stringExpansionRegEx(String str) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]\\d)+");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);

        boolean bool = Pattern.matches("([a-zA-Z]\\d)+", str);
        if (bool = true){
            for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++)  {
                     char ch = str.charAt(i);
                     int count = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i+1)));
                     for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
                         result.append(ch);
                     }
                     i=i+1;
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

}


since every letter is repeated once more than expected, check the limits of the inner for loop (end condition) - compare it with the limits of the outer for loop, which is correct -- this problem is often seen on this site

Btw, the condition if (bool = true) is always true because = is an assignment, not a comparison. You mean if (bool == true), or, easier, if (bool).

It's also easier to do i += 2 in the for loop update, rather than i++ and i=i+1 inside the loop.

Up 1 to @Anonymous for extending the courtesy of providing the reason for the downvote.

@AndyTurner Thank you. This helped to simplify the logic.
if (bool == true){
for (int i=0;i<str.length();i+=2)  {
char ch = str.charAt(i);
int count = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i+1)));
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
result.append(ch);
}
}
}

Since the index of the for loop in this case starts from 0 and the step size is 1, in order for the number of loops to meet the requirement (count), you need to control the loop boundary to "< = count - 1" or "< count", otherwise the number of loops will be "count + 1"
Modify the second level for loop to
     for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        result.append(ch);
     }


Please provide some explanation as to why this works - it's the correct fix, but the important thing is to explain so OP (and others) understand why, so they can apply the knowledge next time.

please [edit] your question to add the explanation. But please note that saying "the boundary should be -1" isn't correct, because your boundary isn't count-1: it's the fact that the condition uses < instead of <=.

Updated working code
public String stringExpansionRegEx(String str) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    boolean bool = Pattern.matches("([a-zA-Z]\\d)+", str);
    if (bool == true){
        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i+=2)  {
                 char ch = str.charAt(i);
                 int count = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i+1)));
                 for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                     result.append(ch);
                 }
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}


Experienced programmers reading your code will prefer the terser if (bool) over if (bool == true). You may also explain in words what changes you made and how it solved your issue. So we don‘t have to analyse the difference character by character ourselves.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

One of the reasons if (bool) is preferred, as said by @Anonymous, aside from the conciseness, is that it avoids the potential to mix up = with ==.
